# Give full permission to particular Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, permissions, java-web-start, jnlp

I am working on one java Swing Web Start application and need to test it online. But I think  I need to fix some permission issues before deploying it on any server.

Can we make an exception for this application, because right now development is in progress so for my testing I am deploying it again and again?

So to avoid every time signing that jar. Can I make any exception in my browser/system? so that it can run with full permissions without any error.

Comment: No. You have to sign code to get it to run completely trusted. That being said, what tools are you using to build it? Most tools like Maven and Ant have fast, easy ways that allow you to sign jars. Maybe you can research that to make your build/deployment easier.

Comment: Once you make the certificate, it is very easy. I just made a batch program to run the signing on a jar, so when I build it with my IDE, I can just run that and it's set up perfectly.

Comment: @Obicere A lot of times, you can set your IDE up to do this automatically on builds. NetBeans uses Ant, which has a `<signjar>` task, so you can write your own custom Ant target to sign your jars. Maven has some jar signing plugins for it, plus you could always just add an Ant task to your Maven project as well and use `<signjar>` in that too.

Comment: Yes, this is really a non-question.  Sign it at build time as described by @Brian.

Comment: I am using batch file to sign my jar...jar is signed and i created a JNLP (having all the basic tags) to run it..but still it is not opening at all from my browser...then i set my security as lowest from  "java control panel"...now my application is opening but with limited permission. You can check out my page [link](http://searchengine.crazy-minds.com/launch.html)

Comment: Have you checked your `.jnlp`, as suggested in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18145619/230513) on the same topic? Have you tried `javaws`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://searchengine.crazy-minds.com" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>LogSearchEngine</title>
        <vendor>shilpi jain</vendor>
        <homepage href=""/>
        <description>LogSearchEngine</description>
        <description kind="short">LogSearchEngine</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
    <update check="background"/>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+"/>
        <jar href="LogSearchEngine.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.novigolabs.uiScreens.Homepage">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

That should have a security element added.

```xml
<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>
```

After adding it, be sure to validate the JNLP as I recommended in your last question.

Comment: Thanks for the respone @andrew. I have made above changes and have verified my jnlp with "Janela"..Now my app is not opening at all (You can try the same link). If i am puting my old jnlp..it is opening at least with limited access.

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: Thanks andrew..it is working now. But it seems,i need to take care of latest java updates :(

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)